# ERROR: Class 'Greggilbert\Recaptcha\RecaptchaServiceProvider' not found - Laravel - No Composer / Artisan

Tags: php, laravel-5

Added recaptcha package manually - but getting this error

> ERROR: Class 'Greggilbert\Recaptcha\RecaptchaServiceProvider' not
>   found

Done all necessary steps.

- Added the package to the vendor folder
- Added a reference in \vendor\composer\autoload_namespaces.php
- Added a reference in \vendor\composer\autoload_psr4.php
- Copied recaptcha.php to config

Any other steps that I missed?

*Any option to delete all cache manually*?

Comment: Have your tried `php artisan config:clear` and after that `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Greggilbert\Recaptcha\RecaptchaServiceProvider"`

Comment: `sudo composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @AnkurTiwari - I do not have composer. ( Manual only  ( FTP) )

Comment: Seriously, use composer locally, then upload whole result with autoloading classes.

Comment: which version of laravel you have ?

Comment: version 5.5.40.

Answer (score 0):

I installed `composer` in production and ran this `sudo composer dump-autoload` command. That solved the issue. It's not an ideal answer for the question.

Suggest if it's possible to clear the laravel cache manually (FTP), so the ***not found*** error will not be happening